# Python Dictionary to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

How do I convert a python dictionary to a pandas data frame. This is how I currently do it which is not at all elegant.

```
import pandas as pd
MyDict={'key1':'value1','key2' : 'value2'}
MyDF=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(MyDict,orient='index',dtype=None)
MyDF.index.name = 'Keys'
MyDF.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

I just want the 'key:value' pair in MyDict as the rows of a pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
pd.DataFrame({'Keys': MyDict.keys(), 'Values': MyDict.values()})
```

returns

```
   Keys  Values
0  key2  value2
1  key1  value1
```

Comment: Will this preserve the order?. In the sense, will the "key:value" pair in the dictionary converted to a "single row" in the data frame?. ( If so, this is exactly what I need)

Comment: @dineshdileep - Python dictionaries guarantee corresponding order of `.keys()` and `.values()` as long as there is no modification of the dictionary in between. However, there is no order within a dictionary. So your DataFrame will be consistent, just the order of the rows is "random".

Comment: Order of rows is not important for me, but rather the contents of the row. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use loc() to access each row in the DataFrame by key then

```
MyDF = pd.DataFrame([v for v in MyDict.values()], columns = ['value'],
                    index = [k for k in MyDict.keys()])
```

MyDF then contains

```
       value
key2  value2
key1  value1
```

and

```
MyDF.loc['key2'].value
```

returns

```
value2
```