# Convert a dictionary to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I'm trying to convert a dictionary that only has 1 record to a pandas dataframe. I've used the following code from other solutions:

```
d =  {'id': 'CS2_056', 'cost': 2, 'name': 'Tap'}

pd.DataFrame(d.items(), columns=['id', 'cost','name'])
```

But I get the following error:

```
PandasError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Dictionary to Pandas Dataframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34589332/python-dictionary-to-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 55):

You dict has only one record use list:

```
import pandas as pd
d =  {'id': 'CS2_056', 'cost': 2, 'name': 'Tap'}
df = pd.DataFrame([d], columns=d.keys())
print df
```

Output:

```
   id  cost name
0  CS2_056     2  Tap
```

Comment: This works.  I took my original solution from another question but maybe the reason for it not working was because it only had 1 record?

Comment: have been doinf d instead of [d] for almost 30 minutes, thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 8):

Might be you are using python3. 
in python3 we have list there

```
pd.DataFrame(list(d.items()), columns=['id', 'cost','name'])
```

Comment: I had a dictionary of lists, and I wanted every list to be a cell value under one column, not a series of columns. This gave me an idea how to solve that.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative way to create a dataframe with a single row from a dictionary is by creating an empty dataframe first and then [`append`ing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) to it:

```
import pandas as pd 
d =  {'id': 'CS2_056', 'cost': 2, 'name': 'Tap'}
df = pd.DataFrame().append(d, ignore_index=True)
print(df)

   cost       id name
0   2.0  CS2_056  Tap
```

Note that this method is significantly slower than @Serenity 's solution so definitely do not choose this method if you are concerned about performance. 
But having options is always nice.

Comment: it seems this method also arranges the columns in alpha ascending order, fwiw.

Answer (score 5):

Easy command, just make sure you enclose your dictionary in square brackets.

```py
d =  {'id': 'CS2_056', 'cost': 2, 'name': 'Tap'}

df = pd.DataFrame([d])
df
```

Answer (score 1):

While this question does have a duplicate ([Python Dictionary to Pandas Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34589332/python-dictionary-to-pandas-dataframe)), I believe there's a simplier answer than those provided there.

Convert the values to lists:

`d = {'id': ['CS2_056'], 'cost': [2], 'name': ['Tap']}`

then simply:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)
#     cost       id name
#  0     2  CS2_056  Tap
```

Keep in mind that if columns order matter you'd still need to explicitly provide `columns` to `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['id', 'cost', 'name'])
print(df)
#          id  cost name
#  0  CS2_056     2  Tap
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing an index parameter to the DataFrame constructor works in python 3.

```
import pandas as pd

d =  {'id': 'CS2_056', 'cost': 2, 'name': 'Tap'}
df = pd.DataFrame(d, index=[0])
print(df)

# Output:
#           id  cost name
#   0  CS2_056     2  Tap
```