# Convert to dict to pandas table

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dict object. I am trying to convert to pandas table .

```
 {'st_id': 1234, 'dep_id': [{'dept': 16, 'cat: [{'cat_nbr': 8}], 'f_data': [{'fid': '39.3', 'lid': '839.3'}, {'fid': '739.4', 'lid': '9.3'}]}]}
```

Needed the output in table format. Any suggestion for converting into tables

Comment: your dict object seems to have a typo : `{'st_id': 1234, 'dep_id': [{'dept': 16, 'cat': [{'cat_nbr': 8}], 'f_data': [{'fid': '39.3', 'lid': '839.3'}, {'fid': '739.4', 'lid': '9.3'}]}]}` ? and what is the expected output?

Comment: Does this seem to answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42466639/convert-a-dictionary-to-a-pandas-dataframe

Comment: `pd.json_normalize`.