# Correlating values of dictionary - 'dict' object has no attribute 'corr'

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am new to python, I am trying to work with dictionary and correlation. I am trying to get a better understanding of working with dictionaries. But I get an error when I try to correlate the dictionary values for every year, so 2010 up to 2021.

```
data = {}
for year in names:
    tableName = category+str(year)
    n = ', '.join(f'"{name}"' for name in names[year])
    sqlQ = f'select "Date", {n} from {tableName};'
    cur.execute(sqlQ)
    res = cur.fetchall()
    data[year] = {}
    for row in res:
        if row[0] in dateRange and row[0].year == year:
            date = row[0].strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
            data[year][date] = []
            for i in range(1, len(row)):
                data[year][date].append(float(row[i]))
data
```

> {2010: {'01/01/2010': [18.16,
> 59.73,
> 218.41,
> 101.14,
> 44.15,
> 10.0,
> 134.52,
> 40.15,
> 7.53,
> 18.19,
> 24.2,
> 10.38,
> 25.6,
> 48.17,
> 18.44,
> 32.1,
> 9.11,
> 39.73,
> 88.16,
> 23.97,
> 14.19,
> 15.34,
> 45.86,
> 24.25,
> 39.83,
> 43.46,
> 8.07,
> 9.8,
> 7.87,
> 32.73,
> 13.57,
> 39.04,
> 18.68,
> 11.55,
> 22.67,
> 52.97,
> 106.15,
> 47.49,
> 34.16,
> 26.67,
> 61.96,
> 54.09,
> 7.24,
> 14.94,
> 78.03,
> 19.31,
> 34.36,
> 10.9,
> 10.73,
> 35.27,
> 16.1,
> 37.61,
> 16.61,
> 48.65,
> 38.12,
> 26.78,
> 104.99,
> 26.73,
> 22.46,
> 30.68,
> 30.7,
> 65.09,
> 50.28,
> 80.31,
> 19.91,
> 32.27,
> 62.5,
> 6.03,
> 9.14,
> 16.16,
> 24.53,
> 33.29,
> 53.25,
> 168.84,
> 10.68,
> 130.9,
> 30.12,
> 23.01,
> 23.49,
> 80.66,
> 58.73,
> 9.15,
> 16.52,
> 96.83,
> 35.17,
> 15.11,
> 21.64,
> 23.39,
> 24.24,
> 26.93,
> 42.85,
> 24.18,
> 61.75,
> 80.98,
> 30.48,
> 40.68,
> 26.06,
> 3.81,
> 30.5,
> 13.9],   '04/01/2010': [18.37,
> 61.71,
> 223.96,
> 102.92,
> 45.26,
> 10.28,
> 133.9,
> 41.73,
> 7.64,
> 18.89,
> 24.28,
> 10.38,
> 25.68,    ...

```
import pandas as pd
df = data
for key, value in df.items():
    #print(key,value)
    df.corr(method ='pearson')
```

> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'corr'

Comment: If you want to use pandas you have to create one or more dataframes from the dictionary.

Comment: Can you show us data Initialisation?

Comment: you can refer this [python-dictionary-to-pandas-dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34589332/python-dictionary-to-pandas-dataframe/34589389#34589389)

Answer (score 0):

You had to store the dictionary in a pandas's dataframe `df = pd.DataFrame(data)`

```
import pandas as pd
for key, value in data.items():
    print(key)
    df = pd.DataFrame(value)
    print(df.corr(method ='pearson'))
```

Comment: Then it only get the first key of 2010 but not the rest, i can see values for the rest of the data is NaN - TypeError: corr() missing 1 required positional argument: 'other'

Comment: @fallenmcmullan, does putting dataframe inside the loop solves the problem ? Please see the updated code

Comment: I get a lot of empty dataset still then @imdevskp

Comment: do you mind adding the output of `data.keys()` and `data[2010].keys()` in the question

Comment: It prints dict_keys([2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020])
dict_keys(['01/01/2010', '04/01/2010', '05/01/2010', '06/01/2010', '07/01/2010', '08/01/2010', '11/01/2010', '12/01/2010', '13/01/2010', '14/01/2010', '15/01/2010', '18/01/2010', '19/01/2010', '20/01/2010', '21/01/2010', '22/01/2010', '25/01/2010',   but then it ends at end of year 2010

Comment: I have updated the code. can you include the output of that too if it's not working

Comment: When i did it with an excel file and not from database i got this result. I dont understand why it is not the same now https://prnt.sc/12co77f ... I get this https://prnt.sc/12co8mo